# Vuhdo bodyguard integration

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I use an addon called vuhdo to help with healing. Vuhdo has a panel called "Private Tanks", when out adventuring with my bodyguard I set the focus on them, this places them into the private tanks panel. The situation works well enough, but I would much prefer not to have to use the focus in this way. Often the focus will be lost for one reason or the other, and I would also like to keep it free in case I want to use it for something else.

How can I make my bodyguard appear in one of the vuhdo panels without having to set focus on them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VhuDo developers would need to implement a frame for it.
Even Blizzard default frames dont have a bar that shows up for your bodyguard.

This is because the Bodyguards don't have a UnitID that you can easily track.

I do the same thing you do, and set my focus to my body guard.

Here's some more information if you want to have a read.
http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/15355285822

~Edit

Something you might be able to try to do, I dont use VhuDo personally so I have not tested this, is set the bodyguard as a private tank.

Comment: Additionally you could set a macro to find additional people and add them to the focus frame.